# Using projector via Wi-Fi from Linux laptop running Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, display, projector

A local bar hosts a programmer's meetup I organize. Recently they switched out their projectors such that the only accessible connections are now Wi-Fi (formerly I used a wire to HDMI/VGA ports.)

How do I go about connecting to a projector via wifi on Linux?

I'm using a Thinkpad T460, with Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco, the current version of Ubuntu).

```
$ NetworkManager --version
1.16.0
```

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028165/963426) describes solving the problem by installing Miraclecast on Ubuntu.

Unfortunately [the MiracleCast PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/miraclecast) it references has builds available for many older versions of Ubuntu, but not for 19.04, which the question specifies.

Comment: Please edit your question… This is interesting: Do you have any details on the make and model of projector? As well as what the exact version of Ubuntu yo are using?

Comment: My source details added. For the projector, I'll have to visit the venue later today...

Comment: Use `nmap` while in the shop to find which ports are open on the projector, which can give a hint. You may also try the procedure in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028165/963426) which involves installing `miraclecast`. As a remote possibility for an Epson projector, you might try in Chrome the extension [Epson iProjection](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epson-iprojection/eckfnjciamkgacmglbfgficbidfdjpim?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, I'll try those things out and report back. I'll try them at home first, on my Roku, so I understand how they are meant to work, then I'll try them in the venue with the projector I actually want to use...

Comment: The miraclecast ppa doesn't have a build for 19.04 (disco) :-(

Comment: Miraclecast has been [open-sourced](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) with [FAQ](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/wiki/FAQ). For installation from source see [example1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974674/need-guidance-to-install-miraclecast-using-cmake) and [example2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135052/installing-miracle-cast-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts). Don't forget to check hardware support.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have it installed now, but I'm struggling through the instructions on how to use it. :-)

Comment: miraclecast author comments that as of Dec 2018 "miraclecast as a source (ie sending computer picture to external display) is still a WIP" https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues/4#issuecomment-447222047 - I'm continuing to dig.

Comment: There is a branch which intended to address this issue, but it was HUGE (10,000 lines of diffs) and addressed several large issues all on one branch, and the branch persisted since Sept 2016 to 2019 (!) Surprising no-one, the branch never got merged, has massive conflicts, and is abandoned: https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/pull/172

Comment: The miraclecast repo has a wiki, that lists source implementation as WIP https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/wiki/Internals#source-implementation

Comment: On Apr 29 2019, a commenter asks the project author "What is the status of the WIP on source side Miraclecast? I have tried it and end up with an error...", to which the response was "It is not working for me too."

Answer (score 4):

[gnome-network-displays](https://github.com/benzea/gnome-network-displays) is an application that might be applicable.

I can't find a binary of it for Ubuntu. So I grabbed the Fedora .rpm and made a .deb out of it:

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
sudo alien gnome-network-displays-0.90.1-0.fc30.x86_64.rpm
```

Then installed it:

```
sudo dpkg -i gnome-network-displays_0.90.1-1_amd64.deb
```

It needs a shared library that I didn't have installed:

```
sudo apt install  libgstrtspserver-1.0-0
```

Then run the application:

```
gnome-network-displays
```

This opens a GUI window, and correctly lists my home Roku as an available video streaming sink. Trying to connect to that gave an "Error" dialog (no other content.)

(See avif's answer for a suggestion of how to fix this error)

Comment: OP here. I'll try this out in the venue, with the projector I *actually* want to use, and report back.

Answer (score 2):

Just for future viewers, Jonathan Hartley's answer works as far as installing gnome-network-displays and you can do this to resolve the error that happens:

- Go to:
  https://github.com/sdroege/gstreamer-rs/tree/master/gstreamer-rtsp-server
- Install the listed packages, at the moment:

```
$ apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
      gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
      gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
      gstreamer1.0-libav libgstrtspserver-1.0-dev
```

That's it!

**Note that this is still experimental stuff so it's slow & unstable.**