# Choice of file sharing for projector

Tags: linux, video, projector, chromecast, miracast

I have a question similar to this one: [Using projector via Wi-Fi from Linux laptop running Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco)](https://superuser.com/questions/1394332/using-projector-via-wi-fi-from-linux-laptop-running-ubuntu-19-04-disco)

I haven't had a TV for the last 40 years, but the family wants a projector for Xmas. I'm completely unfamiliar with the tech involved. We are a linux only family: one headless server with some vids on it (shared via NFS or possibly miniDLNA), and a bunch of Kubuntu laptops.

I know some projectors can access network shares. I doubt it works via NFS, does it require SMB or other types of sharing ?

Also I've read about casting, chromecast, miraclecast... But that's very hazy. How do I know a projector supports that ?

Can it work headless-to-projector or is a laptop always involved ? Do I need video-to-wifi dongles ? Sorry if those are obvious questions for those in the known.

Comment: No, it's anything but obvious. That said, part of the question doesn't make sense. You're asking about vague product specifications while that IS what *you* should be researching for the specific devices you have in mind and decide accordingly. Hint: There are product running some sort of mobile OS, typically some Android, that can do anything any Android phone can so you can test available software solutions in your own phone even before considering buying the projector.

Comment: Yes, I don't really know what I should be -looking- for. You mean I can do tests by sending videos to my phone ? OK, will do.

Comment: It's as simple as that with a device running Android (there are a few). Whatever works for your phone will work for the projector. Exceptions are, of course, cheap devices running very old and outdated Android versions that may not be compatible with whatever app or apps you end up deciding to use.

Comment: Thank you, I understand a bit better. I've just done a test with minidlna on the headless server, unblocking the corresponding port on my (normally tight) network, and Nova Video Player on the phone: it can find and play the videos. I assume I can install it on any Android projector like you say.

Comment: Exactly. It runs on any Android 5 or newer but prefer anything with 9 or newer.

Comment: Is Android TV the same thing ? They seem to almost all have Android TV instead of the stock version nowadays... I've never seen it.